# Calculating total of an Expression Column in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting, rdlc

I'm having trouble with this error when I want to calculate the grand total using this expression code `=Sum(ReportItems!Textbox154.Value)`
[image: Screenshot of my issue]

And after that I got an error which is

> The Value expression for the textrun
>   'Textbox68.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' uses an aggregate function on a
>   report item.

Is there a way that I can Sum up the whole Grand Total in just a Single Column on my RDLC Reports?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".